# Deploying iPhone and iPad apps on Apple silicon Macs from TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-silicon

With the advent of [iPhone and iPad apps on Apple silicon Macs](https://developer.apple.com/macos/iphone-and-ipad-apps/), I am wondering how I can distribute beta builds of our app to test on the new hardware without making it accessible to the public.

We have disabled public downloads of our app since we are not sure if they will run up to our standards.

> iOS Apps on Mac Availability All of your compatible iOS apps will
> automatically be made available on the Mac, or you can select
> individual apps below. If you click "Don't Make Available," none of
> your existing apps will be made available on Mac.

Is there a way to enable this feature on [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) or maybe through a third party service such as [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/)?

Thanks any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's an option to enable ***Test iPhone and iPad Apps on Apple Silicon Macs*** in TestFlight, you can find this option within testing groups.

[image: AppStoreConnect TestFlight group]

Comment: Searching that for many days... thank you!

Comment: thanks for the answer, I enabled this but my app still not showing on Mac TestFlight app, click the link in email give an err "Couldn’t Load App", any hints?

Comment: holy cr*p that was so simple ... and so hard to google for!!  Apple once again manages to hide one of the most useful features they have added.
Note that I had to quit testflight and relaunch after enabling this.

Comment: it got easier by now, Nov 5. First thing I found.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly test it on a Silicon-based mac machine with the latest Xcode. You need to choose Mac(Designed for iPad) option there.

[image: Check this image]

After proper testing, you also need to verify your application for MAC OS, otherwise "Not Verified for MAC OS" text will be visible under the application name.

[image: "Verified for MACOS" Vs "Not Verified for MACOS"]

In the above image, you can compare the difference.
If you want to verify your application for macOS.

[image: verify your application for macOS]

1-Choose your application on https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/.

2-Choose "Pricing and Availability" under the "General" tab.

3-Click "Verify Compatibility" under "iPhone and iPad Apps on Apple Silicon Macs".

4-Press Verify Button.

Your application will be verified and "Not Verified for MAC OS" text will be removed.

If you require additional information, please, let me know.

Thanks